# whitespace strip and resave .txt in python

Tags: python, text-parsing, removing-whitespace

I'm building a data set of about 30,000 text files I'm using to build a content analysis data set. I'm trying to loop over batches of the files using regular expressions that pull out and delete the data that I need.

Problem: The first file looks great, but each subsequent file prints strings from every preceding file when I attempt to write over the file. Such as:

File 1: Text from file 1
File 2: Text from file 2 + text from file 1
File n: Text from file n + text from file 1-(n-1)
The code looks like this:

```
import sys
import re
import glob

string = ''

for n in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    input = open(n, "r")
    s = input.read()
    for line in s:
        string += line.replace("\n"," ")
    input.close()

    for n in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        input2 = open(n, "w")
        input2.write(string)
        input2.close
```

Comment: move `string = ''` into the for loop

Comment: del string at the end; and I don't think naming the variable string is a good choice

Comment: Additionally, if you're dealing with large text files it would be better to loop over `for line in input:...`, instead of first putting the entire file in `s`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your initialization of the variable `string`

As its outside the for loop, it gets appended with the content of the previous files

You need to initialize the content of this variable each time you deal with a new file

So just move the initialization inside the loop

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling this was much easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

Your `string` variable is not set back to `string=''`. So when you do your `string += ....` you are appending the content on and therefore having your issue.

At the end of your for loop append:
  `string = ''`

Your `input2.close()` needs to have brackets to execute this function to close the document.

Answer (score 0):

[*input* is a keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) change it to input1 and remove the second inside loop. Also reset string at the beginning of the loop each time.

```
import sys
import re
import glob

for n in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    string = ''
    input1 = open(n, "r")
    s = input1.read()
    for line in s:
        string += line.replace("\n"," ")        
    input1.close()

    input2 = open(n, "w")
    input2.write(string)
    input2.close()
```